# Place text in a post php

Tags: php, variables, post, get

I am getting information to place in a variable with _POST as so:

```
$message = $_POST['bandname'];
```

The question is: How do I prepend text before it?

Comment: `$message = 'Hello ' . $_POST['bandname'];`

Comment: What do you mean with before it?

Comment: @Farkie thank you, if i wanted to put more than one will that work? for example: $message = 'Hello ' . $_POST['bandname'], ['band']; ?

Comment: It's not off-topic, it's just a poor question with no research gone into it

Comment: Its not i did not look into it, I just was using " before that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways :

```
$message = "Your text ";
$message .= $_POST['bandname'];
```

or

```
$message = "Your text ".$_POST['bandname'];
```

Be careful though, one shouldn't manipulate $_POST fields without correctly escaping them first.